# c# how to make a conditional method chaining in fluent interface?

Tags: c#, selenium, design-patterns, method-chaining, fluent-interface

I'm developing .NET core app that using selenium, so I've designed the logic using fluent interface that make the code more readable and maintained.

I have a problem which is how to make a conditional logic in pipeline
I followed this [link of conditional builder](https://devio.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/conditions-in-fluent-interface-method-chaining/).

the error here

[image]

here the source code

**BasePage.cs**

```
public class BasePage
{
    public IWebDriver WebDriver { get; set; }
    public WebDriverWait DefaultWait { get; }

    public BasePage(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        WebDriver = webDriver;
        DefaultWait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

**HomePage.cs**

```
public class HomePage: BasePage
{
    
    private Select2 Driver => new Select2(WebDriver, WebDriver.FindElementIfExists(By.XPath("xpath")));

    private TextBox FirstName => new TextBox(WebDriver, WebDriver.FindElementIfExists(By.XPath("xpath")));

    private TextBox LastName => new TextBox(WebDriver, WebDriver.FindElementIfExists(By.XPath("xpath")));

    

    public HomePage(IWebDriver webDriver) : base(webDriver)
    {
    }
    
    public HomePage FillPostingInformationForm(Company company)
    {
        
        FirstName.SetText(company.ContactPerson.FirstName);
        LastName.SetText(company.ContactPerson.LastName);
        return new HomePage(WebDriver)
    }
    public HomePage IsDriverFound(Company company)
    {
        Driver.IsItemSelected(company.Drivers.First().FirstName + " " + company.Drivers.First().LastName);
        return new HomePage(WebDriver)
    }
    
}
```

**Select2.cs**

```
public class BaseElement
{
    public IWebDriver WebDriver { get; set; }
    public BaseElement(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        WebDriver = webDriver;
    }
}
public class Select2 : BaseElement
{
    public IWebElement _element;

    public Select2(IWebDriver webDriver, IWebElement element) : base(webDriver)
    {
        _element = element;
    }
    public bool IsItemSelected(string keyWord)
    {
        try
        {
            _element.Click();
            _element.SendKeys(keyWord);
            var option = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//*[@{0} = '{1}']",
                                            "role", "option")));
            option.Click();
            _element.BodyClick();
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**BuilderExtensions.cs**

```
public static class BuilderExtensions
{
    public static T If<T>(this T t,bool cond, Func<T, T> builder)
      where T : HomePage
    {
        if (cond)
            return builder(t);
        return t;
    }
}
```

and the call as following

```
public void Build()
{
    HomePage HomePage => new HomePage(InitializeBrowser());
       
    var x = HomePage
        .If(IsDriverFound(company), b => b.FillPostingInformationForm(company))
        .If(!IsDriverFound(company), b => b.GoToDriversPage());
}
```

`IsDriverFound(company)` shown error, so what I did wrong here? and how to call this method inside `if` extension in the pipeline

Comment: Please post real code. It's very unlikely that `HomePage` inherits from `HomePage`. Please make sure that you give us full instructions on how to run this code ourselves. We need a [mcve].

Comment: Also a `return this` is a bad sign in a fluent interface. It should be something like `return new HomePage(/* this plus the stuff passed to the call*/);`.

Comment: _"IsDriverFound(company) shown error,"_ - what error? Also what is `company` in `Build`, there is no such parameter in the method and I don't see a property/field with this name.

Comment: @GuruStron the error is  "this method not defined it's cannot be accessed in the pipeline ", company it's a model containing data

Comment: Can you please provide a full [mre]?

Comment: @GuruStron *I've updated the question with online code snipped and screen shot of error*

Comment: @KarimFahmy - `return new HomePage(WebDriver)` is worse than `return this`. You need to make it that the current instance is unchanged and you create a new instance that incorporates the data from the new call.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you missed lambda parameter. The error says
`The name 'IsDriverFound' does not exist in the current context`
so there is no method in the context of Main, but it exists in HomePage object which is passed as lambda parameter into a method.

Check the second parameter - it's exactly the same. The lambda parameter is passed.

Just add `x => x.IsDriverFound(company)`

Comment: it display cannot convert lambda expression to type bool because it's not a delegate type.

Answer (score 1):

Yo have a couple of issues here:

#### Return Type:

`IsDriverFound()` return a `HomePage` while `if` is expecting a `bool`.

you can either change it or create a new method:

```cs
public HomePage IsDriverFound(Company company) => 
Driver.IsItemSelected(company.Drivers.First().FirstName + " " + company.Drivers.First().LastName);
```

#### Class membership:

`IsDriverFound()` is a method of `HomePage`, so it can´t be called from outside of this class if it´s not referencing a HomePage instance. It should be:

```cs
HomePage.IsDriverFound(company);
```

That said, you can try this:

```cs
public void Build()
        {
            HomePage homePage => new HomePage(InitializeBrowser());
       
            var x = homePage
                 .If(homePage.IsDriverFound(company), b => b.FillPostingInformationForm(company))
                 .If(!homePage.IsDriverFound(company), b => b
                 .GoToDriversPage());
       }
```

Where `IsDriverFound()` return a `bool` or the method `If` expects a `HomePage`.

Comment: I can't use `homePage.IsDriverFound(company)` because it will create another instance of selenium

Comment: you can modify it or create a new method that returns a `bool` and doesn't create a new instance.
```public HomePage IsDriverFound2(Company company) => Driver.IsItemSelected(company.Drivers.First().FirstName + " " + company.Drivers.First().LastName);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of a what a fluent interface should look like if you're trying to build a `HomePage` object.

```
HomePage HomePage =
    HomePageBuilder
        .Initialize()
        .If(hp => hp.IsDriverFound(company), hp => hp.FillPostingInformationForm(company))
        .If(hp => hp.IsDriverFound(company), hp => hp.GoToDriversPage())
        .Do(hp => hp.SomeOtherMethod())
        .Build();
```

The builder and the object you are building are two different types.

The `HomePage` object is then rather simple:

```
public class HomePage
{
    public bool IsDriverFound(Company company) { /* ... */ }
    public void FillPostingInformationForm(Company company) { /* ... */ }
    public void GoToDriversPage() { /* ... */ }
    public void SomeOtherMethod() { /* ... */ }
}
```

It's just a plain object with normal methods.

The builder itself does the heavy lifting of building the object, obviously!

```
public class HomePageBuilder
{
    private HomePageBuilder()
    {
        actions = new List<Action<HomePage>>();
    }

    private HomePageBuilder(HomePageBuilder previous, Action<HomePage> action)
    {
        actions = previous.actions.Append(action).ToList();
    }

    public static HomePageBuilder Initialize(/* add any mandatory init stuff here */) =>
        new HomePageBuilder();

    private List<Action<HomePage>> actions = new List<Action<HomePage>>();

    public HomePage Build() =>
        actions
            .Aggregate(
                new HomePage(),
                (hp, a) => { a(hp); return hp; });

    public HomePageBuilder Do(Action<HomePage> action) =>
        new HomePageBuilder(this, action);

    public HomePageBuilder If(Func<HomePage, bool> cond, Action<HomePage> action) =>
        new HomePageBuilder(this, hp => { if (cond(hp)) action(hp); });
}
```

Note that the list of actions is extended for each step in the building process without changing the list from the previous step.

Also, the final `Build` call creates a new `HomePage` and then plays the list of `actions` against it before returning it.

Clearly this is a simple implementation and I haven't added any error handling, but it should be a good start.